# How to convert html entities to readable text?

Tags: text-processing, character-encoding, html

I want html number entities like &#x119; and want to convert it to real character. I have emails mostly from linkedin that look like this:

> chcia&#x142;abym zapyta&#x107;, czy rozwa&#x17c;a Pan takze
>   udzia&#x142; w nowych projektach w Warszawie ? Obecnie poszukujemy
>   specjalisty javascript/architekta z bardzo dobr&#x105;
>   znajomo&#x15b;ci&#x105; Angular.js do projektu, kt&#xf3;ry dotyczy
>   systemu, s&#x142;u&#x17c;&#x105;cego do monitorowania i
>   zarz&#x105;dzania flot&#x105; pojazd&#xf3;w. Zesp&#xf3;&#x142;, do
>   kt&#xf3;rego poszukujemy

I'm using clawsmail, switching to html don't convert it to text, I've try to copy and use

```
xclip -o -sel clip | html2text | less
```

but it didn't convert the entities. Is there a way to have that text using command line tools?

The only way I can think of is to use `data:text/html,<PASTE THE EMAIL>` and open it in a browser, but would prefer the command line.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

With Free `recode` (formerly known as GNU `recode`):

```
recode html < file
```

If you don't have `recode` or `HTML::Entities` and only need to decode `&#x<hex>;` entities, you could do it by hand with:

```
perl -Mopen=locale -pe 's/&#x([\da-f]+);/chr hex $1/gie'
```

Comment: this work perfect `c-v | html2text | recode html`

Comment: Didn't have `html2text`; not sure it matters.  This example fails with `recode: Request 'html' is erroneous`.  Seems it needs to be run this way now with a range instead of a single identifier: `recode html..utf-8`.  A bit strange, but I guess it's all similar translating codes at some levels.

Comment: @Pysis, you'll notice the first version of this answer had `html..` later changed to `html` in 2014. `html` alone definitely works with the latest version (git head from December 2019) or from 3.6 from 2008. Is it possible you have a very old version?

Comment: Just installed to use in cygwin, I think it was from Choco? recode 3.7-beta2

Comment: With recode 3.7-beta2 the command that currently works is `recode HTML..utf-8`.

Answer (score 6):

From [How can I decode HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/576103) on StackOverflow, you may be able to implement a simple perl solution such as

```
perl -Mopen=locale -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_ = decode_entities($_)' email.txt
```

e.g. using your example text

```
$ perl -Mopen=locale -MHTML::Entities -pe '$_ = decode_entities($_)' email.txt
chciałabym zapytać, czy rozważa Pan takze udział w nowych projektach w Warszawie ? Obecnie poszukujemy specjalisty javascript/architekta z bardzo dobrą znajomością Angular.js do projektu, który dotyczy systemu, służącego do monitorowania i zarządzania flotą pojazdów. Zespół, do którego poszukujemy
```

With `-Mopen=locale`, I/O is done in the locale's character set. That includes input from `email.txt`. It looks like `email.txt` contains only ASCII characters (the whole point of encoding those characters using the `&#x<hex>;` notation I suppose), but if not you may need to adapt the above to also decode that file using the right charset (if it's not the same as the locale's one) instead of using `open=locale`.

Comment: You should use the `-Mopen=locale` option so that the text is output in the user's charset (and make that warning go away).

Comment: Any way to decode `&#34;` as `\"`

Comment: @ocodo I'm not aware of a way to *decode* it as such, but you may be able to use [quotemeta](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/quotemeta) to *add* the escape

Comment: I just went quick dirty and treated them first separately.

Answer (score 5):

A python 3.2+ version, can be used in a pipe:

```
python3 -c 'import html, sys; [print(html.unescape(l), end="") for l in sys.stdin]' < file
```

Comment: Cleaner: ``python3 -c'import html,sys;print(html.unescape(sys.stdin.read()), end="")'``

Comment: @ariddell : your version isn't line-by-line, and I wanted to preserve line boundaries; otherwise it blocks a pipe until everything is read on stdin (pipe is exhausted).

Answer (score -1):

`echo -e "\x01\x19"` should do the trick.

Comment: to get up votes you should probably write shell code that will convert `&#x119;` to `echo -e "\x01\x19"` should be possible with sed.

Comment: Also this don't work because it's one character and I don't get it when I run your command.

Comment: \u119 work, but I'm not able to make it work with sed. So far I have `c-v | sed -e 's/&#x\([^;]*\);/\\u\1/g' -e 's/.*/echo -e "&"/' | bash`